# How do I animate the changing of my <img>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm changing the image on one of my `<img>`'s every 2 seconds. What I want is for the current image to slide out to the left and the next one to slide in from the right using pure CSS/JS?(not JQuery).

P.S: Im sure there is a similar question here somewhere but I'm new to web dev so I didnt know which keywords to use to bring up relevant answers.

**JS:**

```
var imageID=1;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
//change the image

    if(imageID==1){
        //how do i animate this?
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="1.png";
        imageID++;

    }else if(imageID == 2){

        document.getElementById("myimage").src="2.png";
        imageID++;

    }else if(imageID == 3){

        document.getElementById("myimage").src="3.png";
        imageID = 1;

    }


//call same function again for x of seconds
setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
}
```

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` for animation, use `requestAnimationFrame` instead as it is optimized for animation scenarios and offers greater runtime performance and better mobile-device power-usage.

Comment: But for trivial animations, use CSS Transitions and CSS Animations instead of Javascript.

Comment: Can u supply an example around my code?. Im sure this animation would qualify as trivial

Comment: There are so many examples here; http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: so iv managed to get it working using a @keyframe (thanks @Dai). Now i want to pause the animation half-way through for a specified time then continue